# Divide two elements using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to do the following calculation using awk: (Element2-Element1)/Element1

Element 1 Position: Column x, Row j

Element 2 Position: Column x, Row i

let x=1, j=2, i=6

Input:

```
0
2
7
2
3
3
```

desired Output:

```
0.5
```

I dont know how to change FNR inside of the AWK script and opening an awk process just to read each Element and then dividing them by using another awk doesnt feel good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: elaborate your conditions: could `j` be greater than `i` ?

Comment: Hi Roman, j will not be greater than i. It will always be the first line of a column. 
Im trying to figure out how to skip possible zeros in the first line of each column right now.

Comment: what do mean **skip**? If the third line starts with `0` - should it be skipped, should the remaining lines be reordered?

Comment: What formula did you use to get to the resulting output of 0.5. Can you run through your mathematics with us, manually, so that we can translate into `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v x=1 -v j=2 -v i=6 'NR==j{e1=$x} NR==i{e2=$x} END{if (el) print (e2-e1)/e1}' file

0.5
```

Comment: how can i catch the 0 in the beginning of each line? I dont want inf as output.
Or is it possible to take the 2nd value in each column, if the 1st is equal to 0?

Comment: In that case use `{ if (e1) print (e2-e1)/e1 }` in `END` block.

Answer (score 1):

> ***j*** will not be greater than **i**.

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x=1; j=2; i=6 }NR==j{ el1=$x }NR==i{ print ($x-el1)/el1; exit }' file
0.5
```

Comment: @anubhava, that condition was not mentioned in the question, that's your condition

Comment: @anubhava, ***j** will not be greater than **i**.*